# Sorting Segment Session Data from Google Analytics API Data by Day

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I am running a script to pull session data from a segment within Google Analytics.  I am able to pull total sessions for a given data range, but I would like the data by day.  How would I do this?

```
def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, key_file_location,
                service_account_email):
  """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

  Args:
    api_name: The name of the api to connect to.
    api_version: The api version to connect to.
    scope: A list auth scopes to authorize for the application.
    key_file_location: The path to a valid service account p12 key file.
    service_account_email: The service account email address.

  Returns:
    A service that is connected to the specified API.
  """

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    service_account_email, key_file_location, scopes=scope)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service


def get_segment_sessions(service, profile_id, segment_id):

    return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      segment='gaid::' + segment_id,
      start_date='7daysAgo',
      end_date='yesterday',
      metrics='ga:sessions').execute()

def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

  # Use the developer console and replace the values with your
  # service account email and relative location of your key file.
  service_account_email = '************'
  key_file_location = '*********'

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, key_file_location,
    service_account_email)

  get_segments(service)

#print odd video sessions
  print_results(get_segment_sessions(service, profile, '9rZpyfi7Rzq2cU3xvZABbw'))

  #print even video sessions
  print_results(get_segment_sessions(service, profile, '7T3JreTGQnuhIa0i3TZsSg'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```